# jquery timer write time remaining

Tags: jquery, timer, seconds

I have a paragraph field where I want to put the seconds remaining from this timer:

HTML:

```
<p>xx seconds remaining</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
window.setInterval(retrieveLog, 20000);
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call it, store the ending time:

```
var end = (new Date).getTime() + 20000 * 1000; // current time in ms since 1/1/1970, plus the interval time
window.setInterval(retrieveLog, 20000);
```

and add another interval that updates the text:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var now = (new Date).getTime();
    $("p").text(Math.floor(( end - now ) / 1000));
    if(now > end) clearInterval(interval);
}, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/b25KR/

Comment: but if i want to reset it when time left is 0 second?

Comment: @Michele: Use `clearInterval`, and you need to pass the value returned by the interval. Please see my edit.

Comment: @pimvdb Btw, to get the numeric value of a `Date` instance, you don't have to use `getTime()`. A simple Number-coercion works, too: `+new Date` returns the same as `(new Date).getTime()`.

Comment: @Šime Vidas: You're completely correct. I prefer `getTime` for its speed though. http://jsperf.com/gettime-vs-plus

Answer (score 0):

Try [this countdown](http://www.hashemian.com/tools/javascript-countdown.htm) script